# How to comment '>'?

Tags: html, comments

How can i comment just a greater than symbol('>') in HTML?

I tried

```
<!-->-->
```

But, `-->` characters are displayed.

Note: This seems a silly question. Whatever, I wasn't able to find a proper solution. As a work around, I commented like this.

```
<!--remove_me>-->
```

Comment: How about using `&gt;` instead of `>`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try:

```
<!-- > -->
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
<!-- > -->
```

**ex**:

```
a > b

a <!-- > --> b
```

**output:** ab